# Remove all but certain tags in an XML document with Ruby

Tags: ruby, xml, nokogiri

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::XML "<root>
    <a>foo<c>bar</c></a>
  <b>jim<d>jam></d></b>
  <a>more</a>
  <x>no no no</x>
</root>"

doc.css("a, b").each {|o| p o.to_s}
# "<a>foo<c>bar</c></a>"
# "<a>more</a>"
# "<b>jim<d>jam&gt;</d></b>"
```

How can I keep tags in their original order? Or also remove nested tags?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
require 'nokogiri'
doc = Nokogiri::XML "
<root>
  <a>foo<c>bar</c></a>
  <b>jim<d>jam></d></b>
  <a>more</a>
  <x>no no no</x>
</root>"

doc.xpath('root//*[name()!="a"][name()!="b"]').remove
puts doc
#=> <?xml version="1.0"?>
#=> <root>
#=>   <a>foo</a>
#=>   <b>jim</b>
#=>   <a>more</a>
#=>   
#=> </root>
```

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look at whitelist/blacklist/scrubbing gems. [Sanitize](http://wonko.com/post/sanitize) and [Loofah](https://github.com/flavorjones/loofah) come to mind.

From Sanitize's description:

> Given a list of acceptable elements and attributes, Sanitize will remove all unacceptable HTML from a string.

From Loofah's description:

> Loofah excels at HTML sanitization (XSS prevention). It includes some nice HTML sanitizers, which are based on HTML5lib’s whitelist, so it most likely won’t make your codes less secure. (These statements have not been evaluated by Netexperts.)

In either case, they'll save you from reinventing a wheel.

Answer (score 0):

If this is just an issue of order and none of the tags you need to isolate are nested, using XPath instead of CSS selectors in Nokogiri should return the tags in the same order they are in the document:

```
doc.xpath("//a | //h3").each { |o| puts o }
```

I'm not sure if this behavior is in any spec for Nokogiri, so you may want to be careful, but in my experience it is true.

Of course, if the tags you're after are ever nested you may need to define what it means to "remove all but certain tags" (e.g. what happens to removed tags and their contents that exist inside non-removed tags and their contents, etc.).

If your requirement is sufficiently complicated such that XPath queries won't cut it, you may need to "walk the DOM" using something like `doc.root.children` and recursively examine the children of each node.